# jquery DropDownLists

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm getting data on pageload on the client side via json for 4 dropdownlists.

I need to be able to save the contents of whats inside the dropdownlists off to a variable for later use on the page.

You see, list2 is dependent on list1. So, when I pick a value in list1, i need to filter out the corresponding values in list 2.

Once this is done, I will replace the full contents of list2 with the filtered contents.

If a user needs to do a "do-over" I would simply move the full values to the drop down list again until it is filtered out once more.

Question is I want to make sure how do I save the values off properly (since they will be an id and text value) to just a var variable.

Going further, when I need to put either the full list back in the actual dropdownlist, what would be the jQuery syntax to do that?

For gathering the collection of values I find to filter that match, I assume I would just have a foreach loop, but how would I assign it to my filtered drop down list? It would basically be like adding values onto a dropdownlist in C# on the server side.

Thanks much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question is unclear, but if I've read it correctly, you need to save the current content of a `<select/>` to a variable, to use it latter on.

Take a look at the [jQuery .clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

---

See this [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/tDTHp/) Example! <sup>shows the cloned `option`'s being appended to a `div`</sup>

**Assuming this HTML:**

```
<select id="foobar">
  <option value="1">01</option>
  <option value="2">02</option>
  <option value="3">03</option>
  <option value="4">04</option>
  <option value="5">05</option>
</select>
```

You can grab the `select` contents using:

```
$(function() {
  var $selectContents = $('#foobar option').clone();
});
```

Comment: This will work for the saving of dropdownlist2 to the hidden variable $selectContents. I was thinking of doing something like below: 
Remove Item by Text
1 $('#ddlList2 option:contains("HTML")').remove(); // The "HTML" is the selected text of the first dropdownlist
2 //This removes items with Text HTML.

When they need to do it again, the second (above) dropdownlist will be emptied and filled again by the hidden dropdownlist (that was initially filled on page load) that has all the items in it. This is where your clone option would come in.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to actually grab the values and put them into an array, you could try something like this.

```
function getValues(dropDownId) {
    var values = new Array();
    $("#" + dropDownId).children().each(function (i, element) {
        values[i] = {id: element.id, value: element.value};
    });
    return values;
}

function setValues(dropDownId, values) {
    var dropDown = $("#" + dropDownId);
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        var newItem = $("<option></option>");
        newItem.prop("id", values[i].id);
        newItem.text(values[i].value);
        dropDown.append(newItem);
    }
}
```

When you want to grab the values, just call getValues, passing in the id of the select element.  Save the value returned, and then call setValues and pass in the same id, along with the saved data.